# pushing a vector of structures into a structure?

Tags: c++, function, vector, structure

i need to create a structure student that will nest another structure called course. and then fill the structure "course" with how many the student is enrolled in along with their id and name

I am not sure how can i pushback the structure "course" attributes into the structure student which already have the structure course as a vector in it

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;

    struct course{

        int ID;
        string name;

    };
    struct student{
        int ID;
        string name;
        vector <course> ofcourses;


    };

    void studentDeclare(student &B1){

        int coursecount;
        cout <<" Student ID: " <<endl;
        cin>>B1.ID;
        cout <<" Student name: " <<endl;
        cin>>B1.name;
        cout <<" How many courses?: " <<endl;
        cin >> coursecount;

        int TempID;
        string TempName;
        for(int i = 0; i<coursecount;i++)
        {
            cout <<" Enter course ID: " <<endl;
            cin >> TempID;
            B1.ofcourses.ID.push_back[TempID];
            cout <<" Enter course name: " <<endl;
            string TempName;
            cin>>TempName;
            B1.ofcourses.name.push_back[TempName];
        }

    };

    int main()
{
    student boy;
    studentDeclare(boy);
    print(boy);

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B1.ofcourses.ID.push_back[TempID];
B1.ofcourses.name.push_back[TempName];
```

are not right.

`B1.ofcourses` is a `std::vector<course>`. It does not have a member named `ID` or `name`.

You need to construct a `course` object and push it to `B1.ofourses`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<coursecount;i++)
{
    course c;
    cout <<" Enter course ID: " <<endl;
    cin >> c.ID;
    cout <<" Enter course name: " <<endl;
    cin >> c.name;

    B1.ofcourses.push_back(c);
}
```

Comment: clarified a lot, so i can access them , this way: B1.ofcourses.name.push_back[TempName]; ,,,,,, but will have to just copy them into it memberwise right?

Comment: @user10798572, I didn't follow  Are you asking whether you can access objects in the `std::vector` by using `B1.ofcourses.name.push_back[TempName];`?